# Testing Angular queryParams with Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-queryparam-we1uj2?file=src/app/search/search.component.ts)

I want to be able to test the param being passed from one view to the other. I want to test to see if the param is there and that the param matches the mock test data I give it.

I'm quite new to unit tests, done a lot of reading into setting up the test in respect to the activated route and passing a param. I think the bit I am stuck on is the "expect". Its giving me an error

```
Argument of type '{ urn: string[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected<Observable<Params>>'
```

**component**

```
 export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    this.getParam();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getParam():void {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params["urn"]);
    });
}
}
```

**spec**

```
providers: [
        HttpClient,
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
            queryParams: of({
              urn: '123'
            })
          }
        }
      ],
...

  it('test queryParam in route', () => {
    const activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ActivatedRoute);

    activatedRoute.queryParams = of({ urn: '123' });

    fixture.detectChanges(); 
    //  tick();

    expect(activatedRoute.queryParams).toEqual({ urn: ['123'] }); // this line giving me trouble
  });
```

If anybody can give me a hand to see what I am doing wrong - here is the [stackBlitz I came up with to demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-queryparam-we1uj2?file=src/app/search/search.component.spec.ts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here :

```
expect(activatedRoute.queryParams).toEqual({ urn: ['123'] })
```

`activatedRoute.queryParams` is not `{ urn: ['123'] }` but an `Observable` that will fire this value.

You can test it like this :

```
  /*
    Notice the extra "done" parameter. It is a function that you must call
    to indicate that the test is finished.
    It is necessary because we are testing an asynchronous method.
    This will prevent the test from exiting until the "done" method is called.
    Also, the test will fail if the done method is not called within 5s by default.
  */                                
  it('test queryParam in route', (done) => {
    [...]

    activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((value) => {
      expect(value).toEqual({ urn: ['123'] })
      done();
    })

  });
```

Comment: Thankyou - i didn't know about the "done" parameter. I hope somebody else finds this question and answer useful

Comment: the only issue I am getting is that "TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined" - but I can see the value within the .subscribe is equal.

Comment: @TomRudge You would not reach the inside of the callback if `activatedRoute.queryParams` was `undefined`. I guess that this error comes from somewhere else. Do you have the line number or something to help you find where this error comes from ? Does it come from the `.ts` or from the `spec.ts` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66034837/usevalue-of-a-mockservice-in-jasmine-unit-test-causes-test-fail

Comment: it was unrelated @Arnaud but you could still help?

Answer (score 0):

Adding since this was the top result when searching `angular test query params jest`

If you are using `const { params: { id } } = this.route.snapshot` in your component. You should also define your `mockActivatedRoute` containing `snapshot` property

`const mockActivatedRoute = { snapshot: { params: of({ id: 'test-id' })} };`
otherwise you might get an error similar to `TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined`